# Where can I read comments on retracted moderator nominations

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

I noticed that few candidates retracted their nominations from 2020 moderation election [here](https://stackoverflow.com/election/12?tab=nomination). Is there a place where I can read the comments on those nominations?

Comment: comments not on questionnaire but on the nomination page

Comment: You can see the comments left by the candidate who retracted their nomination by going to their main SO profile -> All Actions -> Comments. They are distinguished from other comments since there's no link to a post.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The nomination posts and their comments remain public after retraction, even though they are not linked anywhere. The trick, therefore, is having a link to the original nomination post or something that contains a post ID.

There just so happens to be a bot running in the [2020 Stack Overflow Moderator Election Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217027/2020-stack-overflow-moderator-election-chat) room that posts announcements whenever a new nomination is posted, and these announcements contain links to the nomination, which, in turn, mean that they contain the post IDs.

Plug those nomination post IDs into these templates:

- **Post:** `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/<nominationPostID>/revisions`
- **Comments:** `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/<nominationPostID>/comments`

The comments page is particularly ugly, as it's not normally intended to be displayed to humans. But you *can* see the comments there.

When I say public, I really do mean public—these aren't visible only to users with 10k+ reputation or anything like that. You can see them without being logged in.

Technically, the nominations aren't *deleted*. They are merely *retracted* by the candidate themselves, so the nominations don't get deleted or otherwise view-restricted. They just get de-linked from [the election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election).

Comment: [Link to get all the nomination announcements from the bot](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=We+have+a+new&user=10555677&room=217027)

Comment: wonder if this applies to nominations revoked by company staff. As a hypothetical example, say, if Robert Harvey nominated and after that, would be blocked by [some formal rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274114/165773), would regular users be able to see his de-linked nomination

Comment: Gee, thanks for that shout-out, @gnat.  :/ For what it's worth, as an experiment, I did in fact push the nomination button and got a dialog that said "users who have been suspended are ineligible to nominate in an election for one year after the suspension ends."  For those playing the home game, in my case that's roughly a year and a half from now.

Comment: @RobertHarvey this is quite interesting because as far as I know none of your existing accounts at SE sites has been suspended last year

Comment: @gnat: I was suspended for a year on meta.stackexchange before I asked for my account to be removed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know that, what I learned now is that anti-recidivism system isn't local to the site, they apparently put some mark on network profile. Quite a pity that they use it only for political revenge purpose instead of doing really useful stuff like helping sites that suffer from [attempts to circumvent asking blocks](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7020/31260)

Comment: @gnat Yes, as far as I know, staff-retracted nominations would still be visible, since they're not deleted, just retracted. Regarding Robert, were it not for the suspension, he could just apply for reinstatement, without needing to go through the election. He certainly had my support when he applied, but the process was aborted at a higher level than mod input.

Comment: Cody, I just re-checked all publicly available reinstatement procedures and, you know, suspension does not block applying (and as far as I know @RobertHarvey did that, which kinda proves my point). What is more, procedures do not require that suspension would automatically block reinstatement - per my reading company employee only needs to be aware on it and take it into account, and it remains 100% their decision whether to reinstate or not. So it was totally company employee decision to block him, and not some formal rules

Comment: ...As an icing on the cake, I closely followed all that Robert posted at MSE since his resignation post at MSO and suspensions were on matters totally irrelevant to any moderation duties at Stack Overflow, all were matters of opinion that happened to be disliked by particular MSE moderator or company employee. BTW you don't need to rely on my words here, as Robert is very active at MSO you can simply check everything he posted here and make your mind on how probably it would be for him to be suspended at MSE on fair, objective grounds

Comment: @RobertHarvey FWIW you can always count on my vote.